# Calling JSON data from functions on other project modules for use in requests

Tags: python, json, post, python-requests

Python and programming beginner here...

I am writing a small command line Python application for interacting with a REST API. I'm trying to have the function that posts the request call the templates module for the proper JSON data. I can't figure out how do do this.

The relevant modules are:

```
utilities/
utilities.py
condition_template.py
```

The condition_template.py module has a bunch of functions that return JSON data. Each function returns different data based on the type of condition you are trying to create. An example of one looks like this:

```
def alert_condition_user_score(app_id):
    return {
        "condition": {
            "type": "condition_type",
            "name": "condition_name",
            "enabled": "true",
            "entities": [
                app_id,
            ],
            "metric": "metric_name",
            "terms": [
                {
                    "duration": "10",
                    "operator": "below",
                    "priority": "warning",
                    "threshold": ".85",
                    "time_function": "all"
                },
               ...<rest of json>
```

In my utilities.py module, I have the functions that do the "heavy lifting" of interacting with the API.

```
def post_condition(api_key, app_id, policy_id):
    headers = {
        'X-api-key': api_key
    }
    api_url = '{0}/urlfor_api//{1}.json'.format(API_URL_BASE, policy_id)
    response = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, json=condition_template.alert_condition_user_score(app_id))
    if response.status_code == 201:
        return json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
    else:
    ...<rest of function>
```

When the post_condition function is called, I want the condition parameter to call the proper function in the condition_template.py module and return the JSON data to the post function's JSON input.

The above code works, but it's statically set to only load the user_score function. I need to be able to choose the other options from the condition_template.py module.

I tried adding a parameter to the post function and including that parameter in the post request. That didn't work, though. See below:

```
def post_condition(api_key, app_id, policy_id, condition):
    headers = {
        'X-api-key': api_key
    }
    api_url = '{0}/urlfor_api//{1}.json'.format(API_URL_BASE, policy_id)
    response = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, json=condition_template.condition(app_id))
    if response.status_code == 201:
        return json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
    else:
    ...<rest of function>
```

How can I change what function gets called based on another function's parameter?

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to post a different JSON data based on some parameter ? Sounds simple enough if you can map each parameter to the wanted JSON data. What exactly did not work with your attempt ?

Comment: In my last code example, PyCharm just tells me it can't find the reference to condition in condition_template.py. The problem, I think, is that my requests.post syntax is wrong. I'm trying to load a function from the condition_template.py module into the json input. Where you see "json=condition_template.condition(app_id))"